# Sound stops after unplug the headphones in Fedora Linux

Tags: linux, audio, fedora, pulse-audio

I've a Dell XPS M1530 with Fedora 17 installed. The problem has to do with sound; when I start the system is works fine, when I plug the headphones it also runs just fine, but when I unplug the headphones sound is gone (till the next reboot).

pulseaudio -vvvv:

```
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-bluetooth-discover" (index: #6; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] cli-command.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib64/pulse-   1.1/modules/module-esound-protocol-unix.so': success
E: [pulseaudio] socket-server.c: bind(): Address already in use
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-esound-protocol-unix" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Unloading "module-device-restore" (index: #0).
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Unloaded "module-device-restore" (index: #0).
D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to remove event.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Unloading "module-stream-restore" (index: #1).
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-dbus.c: Interface org.PulseAudio.Ext.StreamRestore1 removed from object /org/pulseaudio/stream_restore1
```

cat /var/log/messages | grep pulseaudio:

```
Oct 17 11:37:30 Kris pulseaudio[1491]: [alsa-sink] alsa-sink.c: Error opening PCM device   front:0: Device or resource busy
Oct 17 11:37:30 Kris pulseaudio[1491]: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Oct 17 11:37:30 Kris pulseaudio[1491]: [alsa-sink] alsa-sink.c: Error opening PCM device front:0: Device or resource busy
Oct 17 11:37:30 Kris pulseaudio[1491]: [alsa-sink] alsa-sink.c: Error opening PCM device front:0: Device or resource busy
Oct 17 11:37:30 Kris pulseaudio[1491]: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Oct 17 11:37:30 Kris pulseaudio[1491]: [alsa-sink] alsa-sink.c: Error opening PCM device front:0: Device or resource busy
Oct 17 11:37:30 Kris pulseaudio[1491]: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Oct 17 11:37:30 Kris pulseaudio[1491]: [alsa-sink] alsa-sink.c: Error opening PCM device front:0: Device or resource busy
Oct 17 11:37:30 Kris pulseaudio[1491]: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Oct 17 11:38:02 Kris pulseaudio[1491]: [alsa-sink] alsa-sink.c: Error opening PCM device front:0: Device or resource busy
Oct 17 11:39:52 Kris rtkit-daemon[1255]: Successfully made thread 2199 of process 2199 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Oct 17 11:53:58 Kris rtkit-daemon[1255]: Successfully made thread 2808 of process 2808 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Oct 17 11:53:59 Kris rtkit-daemon[1255]: Successfully made thread 2809 of process 2808 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Oct 17 11:53:59 Kris rtkit-daemon[1255]: Successfully made thread 2810 of process 2808 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Oct 17 11:54:13 Kris rtkit-daemon[1255]: Successfully made thread 2821 of process 2821 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Oct 17 11:54:15 Kris rtkit-daemon[1255]: Successfully made thread 2823 of process 2821 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Oct 17 11:54:15 Kris rtkit-daemon[1255]: Successfully made thread 2824 of process 2821 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
```

cat /var/log/messages | grep alsa:

```
Oct 17 12:22:31 Kris pulseaudio[1447]: [alsa-sink] alsa-sink.c: Error opening PCM device front:0: Device or resource busy
```